# Laravel, array is undefined?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I have a function like this:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        News::truncate();
        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'features');
        $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.homefeature')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        if ($image = $node->filter('img')->count () > 0) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $image_s = preg_replace("/thumb_/", "", $image_s);
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        $id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
        // if news is null
        if (!$news) {
            $news = new News();
        }
        $news->title = $title;
        $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
        $news->description = $description;
        $news->link = $link_r;
        $news->image = $image_path;
        $news->save();
        $this->info('Main article ' .$title. ' done succesfully');
    });
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $image_s = preg_replace("/thumb_/", "", $image_s);
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        //$id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $newsArray[] = [
            'title' => $title,
            'datepublished' => $datepublished,
            'description' => $description,
            'link' => $link_r,
            'image' => $image_path,
            ];       
        $this->info('Scraping done for ' .$title. ' succesfully');
    });
    print_r($newsArray);
    //$news = News::insert($newsArray);
    }
}
```

So I am trying to put everything into an array before saving it, however I get an error saying that $newsArray is undefined? if I put print_r inside the function, just below it I do get an output. How can this be solved? What I want to do is to loop throught each results as it does now, insert it into an array and later on, bulk insert it to db

//Example:

```
 public function handle()
    {
    /* Clear table, set array of id's, and get today's date */
    Film::truncate();
    $arrayOfCinemaIds = [10565,7311,9434];
    $startdate = strtotime("today");
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $startdate);
    /* Set date to today + + days */
    $endate = strtotime("+6 Days");
    /* Check if current date is less than $endate */
        while ($startdate < $endate) { 
        /* If it is less, do a foreach loop for $arrayOfCinemaIds */
            foreach($arrayOfCinemaIds as $id){
            /* Get data from cinelist api */
                $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/'.$id.'/?day='.$date);
                $data = json_decode($data);
                /* Find entities that match api_key */
                $find_id = Entity::where('api_key', $id)->get();
                    foreach($find_id as $id_found) {
                        $entity_id = $id_found->id;
                            foreach($data->listings as $listing) {
                                /* Put each record into an array */
                                $title = $listing->title;
                                $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
                            $films[] = [
                                'title' => $title,
                                'times' => $time,
                                'entity_id' => $entity_id,
                                'date' => $date,
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    } 
            /* Increase $startdate by 1 day, display message, and change $date to new date */
            $startdate = strtotime("+1 Days", $startdate);
            $this->info('Scraping for ' .$date. ' done, moving to next one');
            $date = date("Y-m-d", $startdate);
        }
        /* Insert array of films to DB, display message */
        $film = Film::insert($films);
        $this->info('Succesfully Added Films to DB!');
    }
```

I have this other artisan command, and this works absolutely fine, so why doesn't the one above?

Comment: declare the array  $newsArray=array();

Comment: declare your `$newsArray=array();` outside the function and use it inside the function

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `$newsArray` array inside each function and trying to access outside the function. So, this error is encountered.

So, declare array before `each()` function

```
 $newsArray = array();
```

Then you can use it.

**UPDATE**

You can use `array_push()` inside `each()` function after defining array like,

```
$element = [ 
        'title' => $title,
        'datepublished' => $datepublished,
        'description' => $description,
        'link' => $link_r,
        'image' => $image_path,
        ];

array_push($newsArray,$element);
```

Then you can use `$newsArray` to insert data.

Hope you understand.

Comment: it does print_r now, but it seems that the array is empty

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Use reference of that array like function ($node, $key) use(&newsArray)

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas You need to add above line before the `each()` function and nothing to change other code.

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas you can use array_push() function as well inside `each()` function where you have write code of array.

Comment: I get: [ErrorException]
  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: yeap pretty sure I did

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas I think that should work. I've updated though try latest one please.

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas `$newsArray` is outside `.each()` function so inside it will not be recognized, you need to add something like `use($newsArray)`

Comment: despite using your code and adding use($newsArray) array is still empty, however if I do print_r array inside the .each it gives me the right result

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Have you print_r just after line `Image:: .....` before `$newsArray[ ] = ....`

Comment: Can you add output of `print_r` ?

Comment: Array
(    
)     this is the output

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Now it's difficult to understand what's happening there

Comment: I don't know either to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Declare array and use refrence

```
$newsArray = []
$crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) use(&newsArray) {
    //Your loop code.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
$newsArray = array();
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        $link_r = $link->getUri();
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $image_s = preg_replace("/thumb_/", "", $image_s);
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        //$id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $newsArray = [
            'title' => $title,
            'datepublished' => $datepublished,
            'description' => $description,
            'link' => $link_r,
            'image' => $image_path,
            ];       
        $this->info('Scraping done for ' .$title. ' succesfully');
    });
    //print_r($newsArray);
    $news = News::insert($newsArray);
```

Hope this work for you !!!